# SQL Server and visual basic important connection

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have connected vba to SQL Server with an ADODB connection, I am running a procedure with it what I want is the message from SQL Server like "5 rows affected", "10 rows affected" or in case of error "conversion failed" with msg number is vba msgbox.

Comment: Can you post the code of the stored procedure?

Comment: I haave create a connection between sql server and excel  and i and i am executing procedure from vba but what i want to know is that is there any mean so that i get to know thay my sql procedure has run properly through vba.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock

Comment: Do you send back the number of rows affected from your procedure?

Comment: You would use ON ERROR in your VBA code just like any other time you need to handle errors.

Comment: The best way is if the stored proc ends with SELECT @@ROWCOUNT

Comment: Surely i will post a code in couple of hours

Comment: On error is not working in this case as if i get data type conversion error i am not able to detect that

Comment: Stored procedure not ending with row count and multiple rows are affecting

Comment: You are saying the when the procedure raises an exception you can't handle it? And if you don't return the rowcount you have no way of knowing how many rows affected.

Comment: @SeanLange  there are multiple procedure running in a procedure and i am executing procedure from vba and if the error occurs (like data type error in one of the row) in the mid of procedure the procedure executes and i dont know the error in vba, i want to print or display exception in vba msgbox. Or its not posaible with onerror and rowcount because the procedure has run.

Comment: What do you mean it isn't possible??? If the stored procedure raises an error it will bubble up to your application. You would catch this just like any other error in VBA and display the error message.

Comment: The rowcount is challenging here. What are you expecting this to return? Each procedure can have multiple statement each of which would affect a number of rows. If you are wanting to count of all rows affected you are going to have to put in a lot of code here to pull that off.

Comment: There are multiple procedure running in procedure i get the output as 1200 rows affected, 1500 rows affected, 2000 rows affected   and error like type conversion error

Comment: And the procedure cannot run further

Comment: I am making a connection through vba and in it i am importing data through ssis package and then running a procedure

Comment: Running procedure in sql server